# How to figure out the intercept of a xgboost model with gblinear

Tags: r, linear-regression, xgboost, intercept

I used the xgboost library in R to build a model; gblinear was used as the booster.

The coefficient (weight) of each variable can be pulled using xgb.importance(); however, I could not find the intercept of the final linear equation. Could anyone tell me where it is, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, only if model uses `gblinear`:

Try this:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(model.coef_)
print(model.intercept_)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the weights for a XGBoost gblinear model in R:

```
xgb.importance(model = your_model_name)
```

This gives the weights and the intercept:

```
xgb.dump(your_model_name)
```

Note: even if you try to calculate the prediction manually for an observation with all this data, it will still likely be off. This may be because your parameter base_score is default set at 0.5, which is added to the prediction by the model.